# PowerMockito not working : -java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/mockito/internal/creation/CglibMockMaker

Tags: testng, couchbase, powermockito

I am trying to mock the static method of **CouchbaseCluster.create()** using powermockito. Here is my test class.

```
@PrepareForTest(CouchbaseCluster.class)
public class IAMKafkaConsumerTest extends PowerMockTestCase {
    
    private IAMKafkaConsumer iamKafkaConsumer;
    private CouchbaseCluster mockCouchbaseCluster;
    private Bucket mockBucket;
    
    @ObjectFactory
    public IObjectFactory getObjectFactory() {
        return new org.powermock.modules.testng.PowerMockObjectFactory();
    }

    @Test
    public void happyPath()
    {
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(CouchbaseCluster.class);
       
    }
    
}
```

**My project pom includes the following dependencies:**

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency> 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
          <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-module-testng</artifactId>
       <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-module-testng-agent</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
       <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

I am getting this error log when I run the test through TestNG framework.

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
> org/mockito/internal/creation/CglibMockMaker
> at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.mockmaker.PowerMockMaker.(PowerMockMaker.java:40)
> at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
> at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
> at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
> at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:379)
> at org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.PluginLoader.loadImpl(PluginLoader.java:61)
> at org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.PluginLoader.loadPlugin(PluginLoader.java:24)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turns out that PowerMockito 1.5.X version is broken when used with mockito 1.10.9

Therefore changing the version to 1.6.X works for me.
This link helped me.

https://code.google.com/p/powermock/issues/detail?id=524

Comment: it won't resolve issue. i upgraded but issue not solve

Comment: Updating to PowerMock 1.6.2 helped, this is working in conjunction with mockito 2.0.2. Another useful link https://github.com/mockito/mockito/issues/190.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Puneet answer, there is always a chance that you have several versions of powermock lib in your project, especially when it is a huge one. In my case I searched for 'powermock' keyword through project files and found **powermock-mockito-release-full-1.6.1-full.jar** and **powermock-api-mockito-1.7.0.jar**, both have **PowerMockMaker** class. So, removal of the incompatible 1.6.1 version addressed the issue.